# How to do Matching Nested Constructs with Balancing Groups in python

Tags: python, .net, regex

The function I would like to use is only support in ".NET regular expression".but not in python. The websit below explain detail what it is:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html

The website is contained the answer, but they used a method called balancing group which its not included in python re module. the answer is below:

```
^[^()]*(?>(?>(?'open'\()[^()]*)+(?>(?'-open'\))[^()]*)+)+(?(open)(?!))$
```

may I know what is the alternative way to do it?

My case is like that: transfer a string to list:

```
>>string = 'TZ',(('TA','TB')*2,('TC','TD')*2)*2,'TD'
>>stringToList(string)
['TZ','TA','TB','TA','TB','TC','TD','TC','TD','TA','TB','TA','TB','TC','TD','TC','TD','TD'
```

This are the steps:

1. first step: list.append('TZ')
2. second step: list.append('TA','TB') X 2 times
3. third step: list.append('TC','TD') X 2 times
4. fouth step: list.append('TA','TB') X 2 times
5. fifth step: list.append('TC','TD') X 2 times
6. sixth step: list.append('TD')

May I know how to do the same thing in python?
thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to do it.. It does work but feels it have a better way...

```
dna = "C1,X1,(W1,W2)*2,(W3,W4)?>,X1,C1"
while ')' in dna:
    end = dna.find(')')
    start = dna.rfind('(', 0, end)

    if dna[end+1] == '*':
        if dna[end+2].isdigit():
            insert = ''
            for i in range(int(dna[end+2])):
                insert += dna[start+1:end] + ','
        dna = dna[:start] + insert + dna[end+3:]
else:
    while ',,' in dna:
        dna = dna.replace(',,', ',')
    dna = dna.split(',')
```